# Command options with hyphen or not

Tags: command-line

Why are some commands (among Linux users) run with hyphens and others not?

For examples, `ls -l` or `rm -r` contrasting to `ps ax` or `tar xvf`?

I see it has historical reasons, but they mean the same, why weren't they unified?

Comment: My guess is the one's that don't use hyphens for arguments were written by non-conformists that wanted to make things difficult.  However you would likely have to ask the author of each program to find out why they did it that way.

Comment: @Jesse_b Nope, it's AT&T vs BSD vs the world; see my answer.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, I read Unix Wars and still stand by my statement. :)

Comment: Related: [What’s the difference between a flag, an option, and an argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285575/80216)  and  [Unix-, BSD-, GNU-options in Linux’s ```ps``` command. Where are they from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78691/80216)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The different ways of passing the arguments to console applications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128778/the-different-ways-of-passing-the-arguments-to-console-applications)

Comment: Who would be doing this unification, how would they get everyone to agree on it, and what would be the benefit? (p.s. why does Spanish have irregular verbs, shouldn't someone unify the language?)

Comment: Related: [Why does my ls --help not work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/224451)

Answer (score 9):

For this, you need to go way back in the history of *nix, when you had many flavors of unices. `ps` is especially hairy, because it has totally different options if you use the `-` (POSIX/Unix style) or without (BSD). [Unix Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_wars) is a useful Wikipedia page to start reading about it.

Edit: [History of Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix) might interest you as well.

Comment: I see the historical reasons, but why not unify all syntax?

Comment: @PierreB As stated in [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 Vol. 1 Chapter 12](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html): "some historical utilities could not be changed (to avoid breaking existing applications)".

Comment: Because change for the sake of change rarely works out. Also: it is a breaking change.

Comment: @PierreB because I've been typing `ps aux` for over twenty years and I don't want to change. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The command line option without dashes, as found with e.g. `tar`, `dd` and `ps` are older style command line flags that can't be removed due to too many applications depending on them.

[The OpenBSD manual for `tar`](http://man.openbsd.org/tar) calls the old-style option "legacy" options, but I'm pretty sure I've seen the name "packed options" or "binned options" (or something like that) to describe this older syntax.

`dd` inherited it's non-dashed options from [the Job Control Language (JCL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language#In-stream_input) on IBM mainframes.

Some of these utilities also accept dashed options, and [the POSIX specification for `ps`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/ps.html) does not mention the old-style options at all.  [The specification of `dd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/dd.html) lists "operands" rather than "options", and `tar` is not standardised by POSIX at all (the standard archiver [is `pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/pax.html)).

Note also that newer utilities also uses non-dashed options (or rather, operands) to determine what action to take. You will find these in e.g. `git commit -p`, and `lxc exec` etc.

This is actually rather similar to the "action" of `tar`.  From [the original `tar` manual](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/man/man1/tar.1) in Unix Release 7:

> `tar`
>   saves and restores files
>   on magtape.
>   Its actions are controlled by the
>   `key`
>   argument.
>   The
>   `key`
>   is a string of characters containing
>   at most one *function letter* and possibly
>   one or more *function modifiers*.

The original implementation of `ps` in Unix Release 3 [*had* dashed options](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V3-Snapshot-Development/man/man8/ps.8) (note that the manual section here is 8 rather than 1, i.e. in the section for administrative utilities). In the next release, [it had lost them](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V4-Snapshot-Development/man/man1/ps.1).

---

Note: I'm mixing the terminology for "option" and "operand" throughout. An "option" is technically a dashed single letter or character, e.g. `-a`, while an "operand" is a non-option. Both are command line arguments though.